# Porque a DIV quebra de linha ao ser redimensionada?

Tags: css, css3

Tenho três DIV´s uma ao lado da outra, porém defini que a DIV do meio `(espaco-contato)` tenha uma largura mínima definida, porém, que as DIV´s laterais continuem responsivas.

O que está acontecendo é que ao chegar na largura mínima definida na DIV do meio `(espaco-contato)`, a da lateral direita `(espaco-interacao)` quebra de linha e depois a DIV `(espaco-contato)` também quabra de linha. Preciso que as três DIV´s continuem reduzindo suas larguras sem quebrar de linha.

Segue o link para verificação: https://jsfiddle.net/gladisonperosini/3bohLt7r/4/

Como resolver?

**Segue o CSS:**

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1550px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
}
header div.espaco-logo{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #222;
}
header div.espaco-contato{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    min-width: 450px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
header div.espaco-interacao{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<header>

    <div class="espaco-logo"></div>

    <div class="espaco-contato"></div>

    <div class="espaco-interacao"></div>

</header>
```

Comment: coloque um exemplo funcionando com o problema, só observar o código estático fica mais difícil ajudar

Comment: @RicardoPontual Olá, segue o link https://jsfiddle.net/gladisonperosini/3bohLt7r/4/

Comment: Coloca display: Flex, no header que deve resolver

Comment: @hugocsl Não resolveu!

Comment: Gladison, como o @hugocsl comentou colocar um `display:flex;` resolve. (Também removi os floats, que não tem mais necessidade) Veja o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/0boad2kt/

Answer (score 2):

Se a `div` do meio possui uma largura mínima de `450px`, quando a `largura da tela divida por 3` for menor que `450px` (desconsiderando o `padding` que você colocou no `header`), a div do meio irá continuar com os mesmos `450px` (que é o mínimo definido), e irá ocupar mais espaço do que foi definido na função `calc(100% / 3)`, fazendo com que as outras divs laterais (a última primeiramente, ou as duas) fiquem sem espaço para ficarem ao lado, causando a quebra de linha.

O que você deve fazer mesmo é utilizar flexbox no `header`, como dito nas outras respostas, mas há uma outra forma que aproveita melhor o recurso do flexbox:

Além de dispensar o uso do `float: left` (que não é o melhor recurso nesses casos) pode dispensar também o uso do `calc(100% / 3)`. Já que vai usar flexbox, use em vez do `calc()`, a propriedade `flex: 1` em cada `div` (que seria o mesmo que `flex-grow: 1`). Essa propriedade irá distribuir as 3 divs de forma igual dentro da largura do `header` (mantendo a largura mínima da div do meio definida em `450px`). Se a largura da tela for igual ou maior que `450px * 3`, ou seja, `1350px`, as 3 divs terão exatamente a mesma largura.

O código ficará assim:

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1550px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
}
header div.espaco-logo{
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #222;
    flex: 1;
}
header div.espaco-contato{
    min-width: 450px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    flex: 1;
}
header div.espaco-interacao{
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #bbb;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>

    <div class="espaco-logo"></div>

    <div class="espaco-contato"></div>

    <div class="espaco-interacao"></div>

</header>
```

> Repare que com o uso da propriedade `flex` o código fica mais enxuto e melhor aproveitado os recursos do flexbox.

Comment: Posto uma resposta bem explicada e sugerindo uma solução melhor e vem um usuário e negativa sem falar nada. Esse tipo de usuário deveria rever seus conceitos se está realmente ajudando a comunidade. Lamentável! Esse é o mal do StackOverflow.

Comment: Passo quase 1hr para escrever a resposta, abro manuais, leio, analiso tudo, faço vários testes, reviso tudo antes de clicar em "Postar" pra ver se há alguma coisa errada ou se escrevi alguma besteira ou algo muito subjetivo, aí vem um usuário e negativa. Tudo bem que ele pode não concordar com alguma coisa, mas no mínimo deveria reconhecer o esforço que foi feito e se for negativar (que é um direito), pelo menos dizer o que achou de errado. É isso que faço com respostas elaboradas. Com respostas pobres eu tb negativo sem falar nada, mas com elaboradas, se eu voto -1, eu sempre deixo um recado.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode resolver utilizando o flex-box desta forma:

```
header{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1550px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #eee;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
header div.espaco-logo{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #222;
}
header div.espaco-contato{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    min-width: 450px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
header div.espaco-interacao{

    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #bbb;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

porque essa div  ela tem um tamanho quando esse tamanho da tela não suporta tamanho da div ela faz essa quebra de linha  vc pode mudar tamanho dela usando @media screen and (max-width 480px) so um exemplo ou mudar tamanho.  se voce prestar atenção tamanho da div não muda voce teria que mudar tamanho width para aquela screen.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  header div.espaco-logo{
    float: left;
    width:150px ;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #222;
}
```

recomendo usar bootstrap 4